# Cannot resolve symbol 'view'

Tags: android, android-studio

```
 public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
         // code here
     }
```

> I am writing this code in android studio and it is giving me error that, "**Cannot resolve symbol 'view'.**" I have already imported android.view.View, but this doesn't solve my problem. Any help would be appreciated.
>   Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `public void onCheckboxClicked(View view)` instead of `public void onCheckboxClicked;(View view;)`

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of unnecessary semicolons, the correct code should be

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon after `onCheckboxClicked` and after `view`

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view){
    //...
}
```